# How was a rude and offensive comment handled?

Tags: support, comments, offensive

I have received a rude/offensive comment on [one of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24680440/2140173).

As soon as I flagged it as an offensive comment it immediately disappeared from the comments section. I can see it was marked as "helpful" in my flagging history right away.

Was this somehow handled automatically or did a moderator handled it within literally a second of flagging it?

How are offensive/rude comments actually handled?

Comment: See [How does comment voting and flagging work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work) on [metase].

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There were some words in the comment that mean that as soon as it was flagged as offensive, it got deleted immediately.

Comment: Ok cool that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, there are a few words/phrases that will do that ;)

Comment: Like "synergizing" and "retroactive proactiveness".

Comment: @J.Steen - I can't unsee that comment. ugh.