# Clarify guidelines for flagging words or phrases we perceive to be offensive?

Tags: discussion, flags, offensive

I flagged [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661766/c-convert-a-mixed-case-string-to-all-lower-case/16683928#16683928). SO took me through the process where it asked for the reason for flagging (I chose "offensive") and explained that you should only choose this if "a reasonable person would consider it rude, offensive, or hate speech". Later, I checked my user profile to find that the flag had been declined because "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it".

So, logically, either the flag should be accepted, or else I am not a reasonable person.

... Or maybe SO could use a better guideline for the "offensive" flag.

The reason I flagged the answer is that it uses the word "ghetto", which I and many other people (easily seen from a Google search) consider racist. Are we reasonable or not? I don't think it can, or should, be up to SO moderators to make that call.

For the specific case of "ghetto", could that be put in a list of words that are automatically flagged? It's not at all necessary for on-topic discussions on SO. This would mean more consistent moderation and a reduced workload for moderators.

For the broader case of the "offensive" flag, what would be a better guide than "a reasonable person"? What's worked in other communities?

Edit: **I am not asking: "Is the word 'ghetto' racist?"** That's the question that many people seem to be responding to (partly because somebody misleadingly changed the question title to that shortly after it was posted). So, to refocus the discussion: **What do we do about words that many people consider to be offensive but others do not? Can posters/editors/moderators have clearer guidelines than the "reasonable person" litmus test?**

Comment: Can't it be edited and salvaged?

Comment: I can't see anything "racist" in the way in which the word is used here. The word "ghetto" itself is not enough in isolation. And let's please not add more flags based on single words.

Comment: [Oxford Dictionaries says](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ghetto): *"A part of a city, especially a slum area, occupied by a minority group or groups."* I personally don't associate the word with race, rather with a certain type of people. But I also don't think the usage here adds something to the answer. In fact I don't even know what it's supposed to mean here.

Comment: The worse ghettos are the ones people build themselves, in their minds.

Comment: Possibly what he meant was the 4th definition of [ghetto](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ghetto) *"(adj.) jury-rigged, improvised, or home-made (usually with extremely cheap or sub-standard components)..."* or "a cheap hack".

Comment: It always depends on the context. For example: "C programmers often live in a ghetto regarding their skills of higher level languages" might still be a valid sentence.

Comment: @Bart: Problem is, the word _is not_ used in isolation.  In the referenced post, it's used in a clearly pejorative sense.  It's [intentionally](http://dcentric.wamu.org/2011/05/ghetto-five-reasons-to-rethink-the-word/) [classist](http://www.blackcommentator.com/132/132_guest_ghetto.html).

Comment: Clearly pejorative towards the use of `tolower()` certainly. And intentionally so @smokris. But not racist and certainly not so dramatically bad that a moderator needs to be involved. Edit it towards a more acceptable formulation that still expresses the same sentiment and you're good to go. As for the "in isolation", that refers to the word filters. The word "ghetto" is not enough to raise a flag. That said, why this particular post deserves all the downvotes it's attracting I do not know.

Comment: As some answers have pointed out, I had edit privileges (which, being human, I momentarily forgot as an option), so I've replaced the word "ghetto" with a word that is not only uncontroversial but also more precise ("sloppy").

Comment: @Bart: Why do you say "let's please not add more flags based on single words"?

Comment: The real subversive behavior is to co-opt these words back from the jaws of the oppressor, using them regularly as normal English words to remove the offensive undertones. The defeatist approach is to edit them out whenever you see them.

Comment: @CodyGray, if you're talking about [reappropriation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reappropriation), that doesn't work if you continue to use the term disparagingly. It only works when you turn the word around and use it in a positive way. If you're not talking about reappropriation, what phenomenon are you talking about? And why would you say that maintaining the status quo is subversive, whereas working for change is defeatist?

Answer (score 22):

In cases like this where something could be offensive but is just used as part of a sentence it would be better to just edit it out. In fact if you have edit privileges and choose to flag instead then it's highly likely that your flag will be declined. (The same applies to flags asking for posts to be closed/migrated when you have more than 3k rep).

Take the example of someone using a swear word for emphasis:

> I can't get this **** thing to work.

it doesn't add any information to the post and in fact diverts people away from the actual problem.

As it can be just edited out then there is absolutely no need to involve the moderators in this. If it had been me I would have declined with the following reason:

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Comment: Aha! Thanks for pointing out the other option. I just edited the comment. Still, can you give an example where "ghetto" would be a necessary part of an on-topic sentence on SO and not used in a, shall we say, controversial sense? Since I'm thinking no such example exists, I'm suggesting that the process would be easier and less error-prone if it didn't have to go through manual editing.

Comment: Whether "ghetto" can be used legitimately or not is not the issue here. What is the issue is that something was flagged for moderator attention that could (and indeed *should*) have been handled by making an edit instead.

Comment: I made it the issue in my question. Although the problem I gave as an example is solved, I had also asked about automatically flagging "ghetto" and clarifying the guidelines for offensive comments. Let's have that discussion. (See my comment on @smokris's answer.)

Comment: @jlstrecker - sorry, I missed that part of the original question. However, my point still stands - something that could have been dealt with via an edit was flagged for moderator attention. The flag was correctly declined, though I admit it might have been declined with the wrong reason.

Comment: @jlstrecker: To co-opt an idea from your own question, here is an example where *ghetto* is a necessary part of a sentence that's perfectly on-topic for SO: "I'm trying to build a text processing system in which *ghetto* and similar words are automatically filtered."

Comment: @BenVoigt: Clever :) You might want to check out my answer, which talks about distinguishing the contexts in which a word may or may not be considered appropriate for SO.

Answer (score 16):

Speaking as someone whose ancestors lived in the original ghettos, I see no problem with the use of the word metaphorically. It's a perfectly fine bit of standard English.

Comment: This is the most sensible direct answer to the question. I don't think anyone other than the OP would seriously entertain the idea that the word "ghetto" is racist. What next, is "chair" racist because a member of a minority group once sat in one? Crazy world.

Comment: @Clive  I think you've misunderstood the way the word is used in htis particular instance: it's being used as a pejorative adjective. You are mistaken in thinking the offence is only in the eyes of the OP.

Comment: It isn't pejorative. See AndrewT's comment on the OP.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers Not at all, you've just misunderstood the definition of the word, and how it's being used. Any others who have taken offence are doing the same thing. "Ghetto" is not a racist word, simple as that.

Comment: @RoryAlsop "usually with extremely cheap or substandard components" sounds pejorative to me. It's using "ghetto" as an indicator of poor quality work. Together with the ethnic connotations embedded in "ghetto", that's going to be offensive to quite a few people.

Comment: @bmargulies, are you saying that your opinion on the word is more valid than mine?

Comment: @jlstrecker Just adding a data point.

Answer (score 4):

Being reasonable seems, in some cases, subjective. Some people will find you reasonable others may not.

As a person, it is the distribution of reasonable vs. unreasonable actions you commit what determines the type of person you are. So far we only have one data point to judge you.

As for that data point, it is difficult to judge whether you are being unreasonable or not. Depends on each person. For me the word 'ghetto' has some negative connotation. But may be ignorance in my part, as I am not a native English speaker and I have not used that word before, so it is not clear to me all the possible connotations. It has though a negative connotation in Spanish, so I would try to avoid it. It certainly does not look nice in the answer you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

### Who should decide what counts as "offensive" within StackOverflow?

Currently, the decision is made jointly by:

- People who post questions/answers/comments. Since they have an incentive to avoid having their posts flagged (since the post might be deleted), presumably many are making an effort to avoid language that they understand to be offensive.
- People (with over 15 rep) who flag posts as "offensive".
- People (with over 2000 rep) who edit posts to remove words that they themselves find offensive.
- Moderators who decide whether to accept an "offensive" flag.
- An [automated system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265364/how-was-a-rude-and-offensive-comment-handled) in the site that checks if a post contains a banned word.

I suggest keeping all of the same people in the loop, but making the process more transparent and consistent.

### How should words be deemed "offensive" within StackOverflow?

Currently, this decision is made case-by-case (for each post) by the people above, based on some extremely brief and vague guidelines. As the discussion on this question illustrates, different people interpret those guidelines vastly differently. What one person considers offensive, another may not. So, currently, the decision of whether something counts as offensive within SO is extremely subjective and arbitrary. Although there's necessarily going to be some subjectivity and arbitrariness, there's plenty of room for improvement over the current process.

Before I suggest some improvements, here are the assumptions I'm working with (stated explicitly in order to address comments that people have made on this question so far):

Assumption: A word can be considered offensve for the purposes of SO posts even if some SO community members don't personally consider it offensive. Note that this is not introducing any new assumptions into SO. The fact that SO even has an "offensive" flag — despite the many "free speech" arguments out there, advocating that people should be able to say whatever they want on the internet — means that the SO community has *already* made the decision to privilege some viewpoints over others. We *already* consider some words "offensive" for the purposes of SO even if not all SO users would personally consider them offensive.

Assumption: The decision to deem a word, or certain uses of the word, "offensive" is based on the historical and cultural context of the word, as understood from the perspective of the people making the decision. Again, this is not introducing any new assumptions into SO. When you flag a post as "offensive", the SO dialog doesn't ask you to objectively prove that the post is offensive. That would be impossible, since "offensive" is a subjective term. (However, the dialog does optionally allow you to provide a reason for marking the post as offensive, which is an excellent opportunity to explain the historical and cultural context and cite references.)

Assumption: The SO community intends to limit discussion to a very specific type of programming-related questions and answers, and wants to avoid discussion that (to quote @ChrisF's answer) "doesn't add any information to the post and in fact diverts people away from the actual problem". (Personally, as an SO user for several years, this is what attracted me to SO in the first place and keeps me coming back. Although, lately, having encountered more posts that gratuitously use words that distract me from the programming issue, I'm becoming more inclined to use alternative sites.) Once again, not a new assumption.

Assumption: We're just talking about SO here, not any other StackExchange site.

With all those assumptions in place, here's my proposal:

- The SO community publishes their list of words that are deemed "offensive" within some context. For each word, the list would include an explanation of the contexts in which the word is (and is not) considered offensive, the reason it's considered offensive, and a list of non-offensive words that might be good replacements for that word.
- SO users with a certain amount of reputation can post somewhere (Meta SO? a dedicated webform?) to suggest that a word be added to the list. (Perhaps this could be linked from the dialog for flagging posts.)
- The SO community then has the opportunity to discuss certain issues about the word:

  - What groups of people consider the word (or certain uses of it) offensive, and why?
  - In what ways can the word be used? Which of these ways do those groups consider offensive?
  - How relevant/constructive is the word toward discussions on SO?
  - How does this word compare to other words that were previously accepted (or not) into the list of offensive words? Is there any precedent?
- The moderators have the final say in whether the word ends up being added to the list of offensive words. One or more moderators look at the points brought up by the discussion, weighing the utility of the word against its potential for offense, and make a decision.

### How should SO handle words deemed "offensive"?

Having a public list of words considered offensive within SO (along with explanation and suggested replacement words) would simplify the work of editors and moderators. If they're not sure if a word is acceptable to use on SO, they could easily look it up. That by itself would make editor/moderator decisions more consistent, by allowing the decision to be made once and then reused.

Even better, SO could automate parts of the process and build it into the UI:

- When a user posts a question/answer/comment containing a word on the list, they could get a warning that their post is ilkely to be edited or flagged (as @smokris suggested in another answer).
- When content containing a word on the list is posted, it could be automatically flagged or marked as needing review.
- When a user edits or moderates a post, they see a message explaining why it was flagged/marked. They're asked to check if the word is being used in a way that's offensive according to the word list.
- Each SO user would have the option to hide all posts containing words on the list, or at least block out the words themselves. (This would not affect what other users see, only what that one user sees.)

### Summary

The SO community goes to a lot of effort to keep posts relevant to a narrowly defined scope of discussion about programming. SO has an elaborate system of incentives and UI features to steer the community toward that goal. SO is all about sharing information efficiently, and encourages discussions and decision-making to happen transparently.

Unfortunately, SO's handling of potentially offensive posts don't keep up with those ideals. It's ad hoc, opaque, and overly manual. It's not geared toward keeping the community focused on programming issues.

To better handle potentially offensive words, I suggest that the SO community establish a public list of those words, engage in constructive discussion to determine which words should go on the list, and use the list to make editing/moderating more efficient and consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Ghetto wasn't a word invented by the Nazis. A Ghetto is an area in a city where only or mostly a minority lives.

It all depends on the spirits where things were said.

Also, if you feel that this certain phrasing is offensive for you, and you think that it could be phrased differently to be more neutral without changing the meaning of the post, you can always edit it. You have the 2k editing privileges already.

Comment: the usage in this context is as an adjective, not a noun. The definition of ghetto you've given here is only one of several acceptances, and not the one that's relevant in this case. In this case, the use is of "ghetto" as a pejorative adjective.

Comment: EnergyNumbers - no. In 'your' opinion it is a pejorative adjective. You can't make assumptions that that is the case for anyone else.

Comment: @RoryAlsop - You seem to be confusing "pejorative" and "offensive". "Pejorative" means that it was expressing contempt or disapproval — which it clearly was (toward the `tolower()` function).

Comment: Nope - no confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Several commenters have mentioned surprise that the example referenced in the original post could be hurtful — so apparently **etymological awareness** is a problem.

Perhaps, rather than forbidding certain words from being used, we could detect language that has high potential to cause harm, and provide an explanation to uninformed posters.

As an example (using the example cited in the original post), client-side JavaScript code could perform a simple English part-of-speech analysis — if the word "ghetto" appears as an adjective, we could display a message like this below the preview:

> It looks like you've used the word "ghetto" as a negative adjective.  Using the word in this sense may have connotations you didn't intend.  For example, it [invokes stereotypes alleging implicit inferiority of those residing in a ghetto](http://dcentric.wamu.org/2011/05/ghetto-five-reasons-to-rethink-the-word/).
>
> If you're using the word "ghetto" to mean something like "sloppy", "careless", "lazy", "jury-rigged", or "substandard", please reword your text in a way that has less potential for inadvertently causing harm.  Use a word that carries less of a loaded connotation, like those listed here.
>
> Or, check this box:
>
> [ ] I'm aware of the etymological history of my use of this word, and believe using the word in this sense is necessary for my text to be easily understood.

Altering the text to avoid the issue (or checking the checkbox) would be required in order to submit the form.

Comment: Problem with this: Who would pay attention? Tick and go, my friend. Tick and go.

Answer (score -1):

Stack Overflow's [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) guidelines include this principle:

> Treat others with the same respect you’d want them to treat you

This guideline is problematic since it's vague (What does Stack Overflow understand "respect" to mean?) and requires the impossible, omniscience-requiring task of discerning "the same respect" the poster would want.  And it encourages the sort of "It doesn't hurt me, so therefore it can't be hurtful to anyone" arguments exemplified in many of the comments and answers on this post.

Since [moderators sweep problems like this under the rug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270414/64860), flagging won't help.  It may be more effective to edit and remove the hate speech yourself.  (Though, in my experience, edits removing irrelevant hate speech from high-ranking users tend to get rejected/reverted.)

Comment: There is no "intentionally sweeping problems like this under the rug". What is happening here is "hey, you have the tools to deal with it. Deal with it" at most.

Comment: Maybe unintentionally, though. I had asked for a systematic approach to dealing with words like "ghetto", which come up in many posts, and that answer did not address the larger problem. It puts the burden on people who find the word "ghetto" offensive to edit each case of it one-by-one, rather than asking posters to take some responsibility to avoid being offensive.

Comment: @jlstrecker but how is that going to be possible? I don't consider 'ghetto' to be offensive, so I wouldn't have a problem including it in a post (now I realise others might find it offensive, I probably wouldn't, but that's neither here nor there). You _do_ find it offensive, so you would have no problem removing it from the post (and, unless of course it's fundamental to the post, I wouldn't have a problem with that removal). But how are you going to police this _before_ the fact, considering that there's no way to define 'offensive' as a blanket term?

Comment: It's a hard problem, and we can't solve it perfectly, but can't we try to do better than the current process? Many other communities are dealing with the same issue. Maybe they have better guidelines for "offensive" or a better process for flagging comments. For example, I had suggested adding "ghetto" to a list of words that are automatically flagged (or marked as needing editing).

Comment: @jlstrecker I see what you're saying, but surely you appreciate there's a burden on you to prove that 'ghetto' is an offensive word? I mean, where does this end? If I decide tomorrow that 'cat' is offensive, can I get it struck off the list of allowed words? I'm obviously using that as an example of one of the extremes, but my point is: Who is going to make the decision on what's offensive and what's not? Especially as you've already said you don't want moderators to do that

Comment: "Ghetto", used derogatorily, is offensive to myself and many people. That much is easy to prove; just Google "ghetto racist". OTOH, "Cat racist" clearly does not have the same kind of Google results :) I gather from other comments that there's already a list of blocked words. Who makes the decision on that list? Or, more generally, can the process be improved to better account for the fact that "offensive" is somewhat subjective? The moderators are still going to have to make decisions, but they could make more consistent decisions if they had clearer guidelines.

Comment: Yeah, the "cat" thing was a dumb example, obviously :) But there are many words in between "cat" and "ghetto" that are probably going to fall into this bracket of offending some people, but being perfectly reasonable and normal words to others. I had literally never considered that ghetto could be an offensive word (maybe because we don't really refer to them as such in the UK, we have other words), and I'm sure there are many people in the same situation as me...

Comment: ...this isn't a case of "not offensive to me, don't care", as the OP of this answer is suggesting, it's more "seriously? the word 'xxx' is offensive in your world? Wow, it's not in mine. I use that every day, and I don't see any reason to stop. Just know that when I say it, it's not derogatory". I see what you're going for, I just don't see a way to implement it, and as a personal opinion I wouldn't like to see it.

Comment: @Clive, maybe the reason you're seeing the problem as intractable, and I'm not, is because you're thinking editors/moderators would need to divine the intent of the person who posted. If they're like "that's so ghetto", but they themselves don't think of the word as offensive or mean it to offend, then you're saying (IIUC) that their words are therefore not offensive. Yeah, it's impossible to read somebody's mind, but is that necessary or relevant? If someone says that the phrase "that's so ghetto" is offensive (as you say) "in their world", and that it hurts them when people say it, ...

Comment: ... do you disbelieve that they're truly hurt? Or do you think it's OK for you to hurt them? Or what are you thinking? In "my world", it makes sense to avoid hurting people, especially in cases like this where you only have to go slightly out of your way to do it. I mean, why not? So, in terms of deciding what is offensive, if we can start with the premise that it's not OK to hurt people (regardless of whether you intended to), then I think it's very tractable to come up with a some heuristics for what consititutes hurting people. (I'll post them as an answer later when I have more time.)

Comment: @jlstrecjer No I'm not saying that you don't find the word offensive, I'm saying _I_ don't. How do I know you're not being over-sensitive? Like I said, where I come from that word is not offensive, never has been. This is the point you haven't been able to address yet: who decides what an offensive word is here? You want to block an arbitrary set of words, why do you (or any other individual) get to pick those words? What makes your point of view more valid than everyone else's? If you stop concentrating on this single word for a minute I think you'll understand the point I'm making

Comment: Let me give you something else to consider. Say I want to ask a technical musical question about Elvis Presley's timeless classic "In the Ghetto", on an appropriate SE music site. You've just stopped me from asking it with your word filter. Why? Is that sensible? Have you made the world a better or more tolerant place? Of course not; it would be a farcical situation to be in. That one small example illustrates perfectly why blocking words that aren't offensive in and of themselves, and only become offensive **in a certain context**, such as "ghetto", cannot be universally banned.

Comment: @Clive - Well, that answers my question of "do you disbelieve they're truly hurt" — yes, you do. You put the burden on the person who says they're offended (at least, if the word doesn't also offend you) to somehow prove that the word is objectively offensive. Impossible. Let's approach the problem from a different angle: Since (as I've repeatedly pointed out) many people find the pejorative adjective offensive, and give historical and cultural reasons for that, then let's seriously consider deeming it "offensive" for the purposes of SO.

Comment: BTW, I never said ban the word "ghetto" from all of SE. Nor do I think it should be banned from SO if there are on-topic and non-pejorative ways it would be used. At the least, I do think it would be helpful to automatically show a message for posters/editors when a post uses the word (with explanation of when / why / to whom it's offensive), and to automatically mark comments containing the word as needing the attention of an editor or moderator.

Comment: Yep, you keep pointing it out, and I keep asking for proof...and I haven't seen any yet, except that you said I should do some Google searches and it will be obvious. If it's obvious, you can provide an official source that tells me the word "ghetto" is offensive, no? But you're still missing the point, and haven't answered the question I've posed to you several times: who is the authority that gets to decide which words are offensive and which aren't? If we implement this, where does the list of words come from? Without that I'm afraid you don't have a reasonable argument here.

Answer (score -2):

SO could follow the example of League of Legends, which has a [machine learning system for handling racism, sexism, and homophobia](http://mic.com/articles/122046/league-of-legends-uses-artificial-intelligence-to-curb-harassment).